# Как завершить процесс python multiprocess

Tags: python

у меня есть процесс хочу по его названию( не по PID ) завершить его, как это реализовать?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста в вопросе, где у вас есть процесс?

Answer (score 2):

непонятно что имеется виду, если это рукотворный multiprocess процесс, то соответственно есть и его объект, у которого есть имя и метод terminate, берете объект процесса, сравниваете его имя, и при необходимости завершаете через terminate

```
import multiprocessing, time, random

def test(s, m=500):
    while m > 0:
        print(f'{s} = {m} ')
        m -= 1
        time.sleep(.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    count = 3
    prcss = [multiprocessing.Process(name=f'test_{r}', target=test, args=[f'run_test_{r}']) for r in range(count)]
    pnames = [p.name for p in prcss]  # имена процессов
    for p in prcss:
        p.start()

    while prcss:
        for p in prcss:
            name = random.choice(pnames)
            if p.name == name:  # завершить по его названию
                p.terminate()
                prcss.remove(p)
                print(f'KILL {p}')
                break
        time.sleep(1)
```

если это сторонний процесс, то через psutil

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == 'test process':  # завершить по его названию
        proc.kill()
        break
```